# Kivy : How to get coordinates in FloatLayout(without kv)?

Tags: kivy

I want to get center(or top, etc.) coordinates of `FloatLayout`. I did well by using `on_touch_up` event but I can't get it in `__init__` part.
How do I modify my code to get `center_1`?

I tried `to_local` , `to_window` , `to_parent` but I could not get it well...

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TestLayer(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pos_hint = {'top':1, 'x':0}
        self.size_hint_x = 1
        self.size_hint_y = 1

        print('center_0 : %s, %s' % (self.center_x, self.center_y))
        # >> center_0 : 50, 50
        # How to get 'center_1' at this def without using 'on~' event?

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == 'left':

                print('center_1 : %s, %s' % (self.center_x, self.center_y))
                # >> center_1 : 400, 300

        return super(TestLayer, self).on_touch_up(touch)

class TestScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        layer = TestLayer()
        self.add_widget(layer)

sm = ScreenManager()

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positions and sizes of widgets are still default values in the `__init__()` method and the values are not useful until the widget is displayed. You can use `Clock.schedule_once()` to run a method after the widget is displayed. So you can get this information with some changes to your `TestLayer`:

```
class TestLayer(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pos_hint = {'top':1, 'x':0}
        self.size_hint_x = 1
        self.size_hint_y = 1

        print('center_0 : %s, %s' % (self.center_x, self.center_y))
        # >> center_0 : 50, 50
        # How to get 'center_1' at this def without using 'on~' event?
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_coords, 1)

    def get_coords(self, dt):
        print('center_2 : %s, %s' % (self.center_x, self.center_y))
```

The `Clock.schedule_once(self.get_coords, 1)` schedules a call to `get_coords` in 1 second.

Another way to get the coordinates without using `kivy.clock` is to make the first `Screen` just a dummy, then switch to the 'test' `Screen`, and use the `on_enter` method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class TestLayer(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pos_hint = {'top': 1, 'x': 0}
        self.size_hint_x = 1
        self.size_hint_y = 1

        print('center_0 : %s, %s' % (self.center_x, self.center_y))
        # >> center_0 : 50, 50
        # How to get 'center_1' at this def without using 'on~' event?


class TestScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('init TestScreen')
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layer = TestLayer()
        self.add_widget(self.layer)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print('center_3 : %s, %s' % (self.layer.center_x, self.layer.center_y))


sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())  # start with no transition for speed (can change it later)


class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(Screen(name='first'))   # start with a dummy 'first' Screen
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        sm.current = 'test'  # switch to the 'test' Screen
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: I understood about `__init__()` !!. I got the coordinates by using `Clock`. Probably, `self.bind(pos=)` mehod also make it possible...? Thank you so much.

Comment: The second way was also informative. Thank you so much.